# Make app update available to specific country

Tags: android, google-play, app-store

Hi I have an requirement Like I have an app published in two countries i.e UK and Australia Later on I come up with an updated that I only want to be available to one country for e.g to UK so the UK user can update to new version but Australia user will not see any update available can we that. This is for GooglePlayStore

Would be better if anybody answer for Apple AppStore to for the same question

Comment: [This contains some context on the iOS counterpart of your question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/69098)

Comment: Hello @Sarthak .. did the accepted answer exactly worked for the case you described in your question? Was the new version only available for UK users? and Australia users didn't see any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Go to your [Play Console.](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)
>
> 1. Select an app.
> 2. Select Release management > App releases.
> 3. Next to the track you want to update, select Manage.
> 4. In the "Country availability" section, select Manage availability.
> 5. Review the table that shows the countries enabled.
>
> > > Synced with production: Country availability for your alpha or beta release matches your app's production availability.
> > >
> > > Customize availability: You can select country availability for your app's alpha or beta tracks that's different from the production track.
>
> 8. Update the country availability.
> 9. Submit your app update.

For more details, goto:

[Distribute app releases to specific countries](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en)

Comment: Hello @sarthak-chauhan .. did the accepted answer exactly worked for the case you described in your question?
Was the new version only available for UK users? and Australia users didn't see any update?

Answer (score 0):

**Ways to use country targeting**

Here are some situations where you might find country targeting helpful:

If your app has an existing production release, you can launch a beta release in a new country without expanding your production release to the new country.
If your app has an existing beta release, you can launch a production release in a subset of countries while continuing to beta test in other countries.
If you want to run a global closed beta test while your app is available in some countries in production.
If your app is available in production and beta in several countries, but you want your internal or quality assurance teams globally to access your app in alpha.

**Country targeting won't apply in the following situations:**

Any additional test tracks that you create will not support country targeting. To use country targeting, use the existing Alpha and Beta tracks.
You can add users from any location to an internal test. If an internal tester is located in a country where your app's production, alpha or beta version isn't available, the user will still receive the internal test APK.
Reach the right users
To manage country availability across all tracks, you'll need to know the difference between app availability and country targeting.

**App availability**

App availability refers to your app's availability in the production track. When you select a country as available, any future production releases include that country.

**To manage your app's availability:**

Go to your Play Console.
Select an app.
Select Store presence > Pricing & distribution.
In the "Countries" section, select Manage countries.
Update your app's country selection.
If you add a country for a paid app, new prices are automatically added. If needed, you can then edit local prices.
Submit your app update.
Note: For details on how to target a staged rollout to specific countries, go to release app updates with staged rollouts.

**Country targeting**

In addition to the availability configured for production, you can customize country targeting for alpha and beta releases. By default, your alpha and beta releases match the country availability you've set up for production.

Prerequisite: You can customize country availability for your app's alpha or beta track in the following cases:

Your app doesn't have an APK uploaded to production, or
Your app has an APK uploaded to production and at least one country is available in the production track
To change your app's alpha and beta release availability:

Go to your Play Console.
Select an app.
Select Release management > App releases.
Next to the track you want to update, select Manage.
In the "Country availability" section, select Manage availability.
Review the table that shows the countries enabled.
Synced with production: Country availability for your alpha or beta release matches your app's production availability.
Customize availability: You can select country availability for your app's alpha or beta tracks that's different from the production track.
Update the country availability.
Submit your app update.